# Http proxy on Android

Tags: java, android, proxy, http-proxy, little-proxy

I try to create http proxy within my Android app.
I use this code inside `onCreate()` method:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.0.2.2", 8080));
HttpURLConnection e = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
e.setReadTimeout(10000);
e.setConnectTimeout(15000);
e.setRequestMethod("GET");
e.connect();
```

My app throw exceptions:

```
I/O exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080) after 15000ms
```

Then I tried to create http Proxy server using [LittleProxy](https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy):

```
compile group: 'org.littleshoot', name: 'littleproxy', version: '1.0.0-beta7'


public class MyHttpProxyServer {
    org.littleshoot.proxy.HttpProxyServer server;
    public MyHttpProxyServer(){
        server = DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap().withAddress(InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("10.0.2.2", 8080)).start();
    }
}
```

I added this lines to gradle.build file, bc gradle didn't want build app otherwise:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

And here my emulator refused to start app:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
```

When I comment all LittleProxy import - emulator again works fine. So I doubt is LittleProxy compatible with Android? On the other hand I have seen [people had used it previously](https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy/issues/94#issuecomment-118351134)

Answer (score 0):

change the version to be 1.0.0

compile group: 'org.littleshoot', name: 'littleproxy', version: '1.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Exclude only barchart-udt-bundle will solve your problem, because the jar contains native libraries but not include arm build. Add the exclude part in the build.gradle

```
implementation ('org.littleshoot:littleproxy:1.1.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.barchart.udt', module: 'barchart-udt-bundle'
}
```